# Application root path

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to find the application root path with the following code on my local machine(Deployed in tomcat 6) .

```
     ${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}
```

At local system it return `"/ProjectName" eg:- "/Hello"`.

But when i put the same code in a remote server where my application is deployed in production mode it returns nothing there.

Please help me to get the application root path in production mode.thnks

Local URL is `lenovo:7777/BharatWellness/showallpartners.do` and production one is `bharatwellness.com/showallpartners.do`

Comment: @SergeBallesta   Url on Local system http://lenovo:7777/BharatWellness/showallpartners.do      and when i try to get the root path it returns "/BharatWellness".

Comment: @SergeBallesta For production Server  http://www.bharatwellness.com/showallpartners.do  and when i try to get the root path it returns nothing in this case

Comment: and Tomcat 6.0 is there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the DNS mapping for  your production URL and check in server.xml file that to which directory in webapps the DNS is pointing to.

on other hand as you ask- you just need to call a servlet from jsp then why you needed to provide the context path, just specify the URL pattern defined in web.xml for that Servlet and that should work for you.

cheers

Comment: i have specified the  URL Pattern only and its also working fine in  local system but not on hosted server

Comment: you mentioned <img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/PartnerImage?id=${row.id}&name=im‌​age" class="img-circle" width="150" /> in your comment, can you paste the Servlet  mapping entry in web.xml here

Comment: <img src="PartnerImage?id=${row.id}&name=image"   class="img-circle" width="150" />

Comment: In web.xml  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>PartnerImage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.bharat.controller.PartnerImage</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PartnerImage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PartnerImage</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Everything seems fine- so, what error your are getting when your try to run this servlet directly on production  in isolation?

Comment: One more thing i have to mention the Container is ApplicationContext (Spring )Container

Comment: Your  request is redirecting from an  apache server where a redirection rule working for handling just the ".do" extension for your application hosted on tomcat, hence your request should be routed through a spring controller, create a controller and specify the servlet URL in view .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78800/discussion-between-chetan-verma-and-naveen-kumar-mishra).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are experimenting the *root* context path.

When you deploy a web application on a servlet container, it normally has a context path, and the full URL is :

```
scheme://host.domain/contextPath/url_inside_app
```

(where scheme is `http` or `https`)

But there is a special root context, (in tomcat it is `ROOT`) that allows the web application to have an *empty* servlet context path. In that case the full URL is :

```
scheme://host.domain/url_inside_app
```

and `Request.getContextPath()` or  `${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}` both return an empty string.

But it is fine, because when you construct your URL with

```
${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}{$localpart}
```

it works.

[ Reference : `HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()` javadoc : *For servlets in the default (root) context, this method returns ""* ]

Comment: ${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}{$localpart} what is localpart in this

Comment: @Serge Ballesta  actually iwant to execute one servelt from the jsp page to get image from database  by using the following code...<img src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/PartnerImage?id=${row.id}&name=image"   class="img-circle" width="150" />

Comment: where PartnerImage is  extending HttpServlet class and overiding the doget method to get the image form database.

Comment: help me please to get out of this

Comment: Container is Spring ApplicationContext Container